# Declare type of a object key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `XInterface` like so:

```
export interface XInterface {
    foo: (() => Foo[]) | Foo[],
    bar: string,
    baz: number
}
```

Then, using the interface to declare an object I would like to the type of `foo` to be `Foo[]`, like

```
const myObj: XInterface = {
    [myFoo1, myFoo2],
    'bar',
    1
}
```

but as I am already using the `:` to declare my array of Foo, I don't know how to ensure that foo is an array, not a function that returns an array.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: 1) integer doesn't exist in TypeScript. 2) That's definitely not how you assign to a constant. Please fix your code.

Comment: `interface XInterfaceNew extends XInterface { foo: Foo[] }`

Comment: You need to clarify your question a bit. But I'd say you can't and you shouldn't because: You declare `myObj` to be of type `XInterface`. Ultimately you'll probably later pass that object somewhere where an `XInterface` is expected. This context then has no notion of how that object came to be, as such it can only assume what's declared by `XInterface`. Meaning a check whether `.foo` is a function or an array will always be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pattern I would follow. In the future you will pass this object to somewhere XInterface is expected, which does not know if foo is a function or an array. With that in mind, you will always have to check the content of foo. A better approach is to simply convert foo to a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can define XInterface like:

```
foo: Foo[],
bar: string,
baz: int
```

and let suppose that you have a function

```
someFuntion(): Foo[] { .....};
```

so when you define your object

```
const myObj: XInterface = {
   foo: someFuntion(),
   bar: 'bar',
   baz: 1
 }
```

Comment: This wont solve my problem, as the function ensures that foo is dynamically passed. 
If I use someFunction() it will be constant again.